# Sql server configuration manager error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-config-manager

I am using Windows 7 32 bit OS and working on Microsoft SQL Server 2008, and when I open the configuration tool I got this error message.

[image: Sql server configuration manager error]

Then I googled the error and got this below link.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437

Then I downloaded Microsoft® SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2

Then when I tried to install this application I got this error

[image: Error pop-up]

How to solve this issue?? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you write that you are using `Microsoft SQL SERVER 2008`but the download link is for `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2`, which is a different (newer) version. If you are indeed using the 2008 version and not 2008R2 what you want is the service pack for Microsoft SQL Server 2008: [SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27594)

Comment: Thanks,There are four files,which one is should download

Comment: @ShreyasTg As you're running on a 32-bit platform I would guess that it's `SQLServer2008SP3-KB2546951-x86-ENU.exe`.